# Bluetooth Low Energy - capabilities detecting client devices

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I have a client that is the owner of a farm. He wants to get monitorized the 1000 cows he has at a  field. Mainly,he wants to identify the cows individually and checks  to place a tablet near a specific door and check which o  them crossed the door. Is that possible? I mean , the bluethoot receiver is able to read as 50 cows crossing simultaneously the door?Or it overflows the capacity of the technology?  How the system needs to be configured ? The tablet as server and de bluethoot low energy devices as clients?
An explanation will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Bluetooth is the right technology for that. Even if the Tablet can handle that many connections simultaniously, it does not tell you anything about the position of the animal. 
 Basicly it would detect anything in a certain radius, but you wouldn't know if the cow passed through or just came close. 

 To answer the Client-Server Question:
 The Tablet acts as the "Central" device, the BLE sensor is a "Peripheral" device. Depending on the Application both device could act as server or as client. Here: [Introduction to BLE](https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy.pdf) you can find a Brief Introduction to Bluetooth Low Energy with more Details.
Depending on the gate size, NFC could be a better choice.